# Can't see trace output from my SignalR hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, trace, signalr-hub

I can't seem to get trace information from inside my SignalR hub. I am using an MVC4 project and in my MVC controllers trace information is being recorded correctly, however when I use tracing inside my SignalR hub, I am getting nothing.

So for example I am seeing the message from the first line of my controller:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Test Controller");
```

But I am not seeing this message from the first line inside my hub:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Test Hub");
```

My web.config has the following line under `<system.web>`:

```
<trace enabled="true" 
       writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" 
       localOnly="false" 
       mostRecent="true" 
       pageOutput="false" />
```

And my system diagnostics is as follows:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="Example Source" switchName="sourceSwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
      <listeners>
        <add name="GlimpseListener" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <switches>
    <add name="sourceSwitch" value="All" />
  </switches>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="GlimpseListener" type="Glimpse.Core.TraceListener, Glimpse.Core" />
  </sharedListeners>
  <trace>
    <listeners>
      <add name="WebPageTraceListener" type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

As mentioned trace messages from my controller are showing fine both in the Trace.axd page and also in the trace tab of Glimpse.

Welcome any ideas, I've been pulling my hair out on this one.

Comment: signalr uses a module which bypasses all others ... You won't get traces with glimpse or a webpagetracelistener.

Comment: Can you update your question by pasting some accurate screenshots indicating incorrect behavior, showing where exactly you're able to see this tracing messages and where not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Tracing-on-the-server-side

What is pertinent:

```
<source name="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" switchValue="All">
  <listeners>
    <add name="traces" />
  </listeners>
</source>


<source name="SignalR.Connection">
  <listeners>
    <add name="traces" />
  </listeners>        
</source>

<sharedListeners>
   <add name="traces" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="server_traces.txt" />
</sharedListeners>
```

Using a text listener will work as expected, because it can run "out" the "normal" asp.net pipeline.